# Compile multiple CSS file into one using php

Tags: php, css

I need compile multiple css file. 
For example:

FIRST FILE:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

SECOND FILE:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

COMPILED FILE:

```
body{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    font-size: 20px;
}
```

Is there any plugin to do that? (Of course it must support all selectors that have CSS standart and also reverse compiling will be good)

Or how can it be done with PHP (the logic I mean). Thank you.

Comment: Dont know about `Core PHP` but there is one thing named as `Mix` in laravel (5.4) or `elixir` in previous versions of Laravel

Comment: there are a stack of php css libraries, try them out https://www.google.co.in/search?q=css+parser+php&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab&gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=MxjKWcqiLK_VXtmhrbAM